# How to use the div tag in HTML

Tags: html

I am new to HTML and I was wondering how to use `div` tag, because every time I use it it doesn't do anything. What does it do and how do I use it?

Comment: What you have tried so far? If nothing, open source code of any page (for example this one) and see how divs are used.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.ASP

Comment: What did you expect, what did you want to happen when you use `div`s? It's just a generic container.

Comment: When you say "every time I use it it doesn't do anything" is hard to imagine "what' you are trying to actually do. Can you please read into [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Likely they're trying to use it like `<div></div>` and observing correctly that nothing appears to happen, since it has no inherited styling from the browser.

Comment: Everyone listen up idk how this got posted but I did not post it lol

Comment: the initial poster was some "lol" user so something fun is happening

Comment: That's real weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `div` tag works as a block element, meaning it allows you to insert into it content and other elements. It is a basic building block of any HTML page. Below is a simple example and you can follow [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) to the official documentation for further insight.

```css
.title {
  background-color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.something {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  Hello world! I can be the title of your web page
</div>
<div class="body">
    <div>I can be the main body of your web page</div>
    <div class="something"> with lots of other div elements comprising</div>
    <div> the look and feel of the web page.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course you should prefer semantically appropriate tags wherever possible, especially for accessibility.

Comment: Good point and I agree, however that is currently beyond the scope of the question, I hope they do read into accessibility as part of their learning process

Comment: Lol idk how this posted but I did not post it but well thanks for taking your time to do this even tho i did not need it.